# Custom Font Slate Pro in MicroSite

Tags: marketing-cloud, microsites, font

I want to use custom font SlatePro in my Microsite. I have 3 otf files for three different fonts.
How do i achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that sometimes the custom fonts which are externally linked gets blocked in sfmc cloud pages and microsites. There is a work around to this by Base64encoding the font file into css header or css file.

- Basically you will have to Base64Encode the font file and put it in
  your css header up top in your microsite.
  Here is the link to the [site](https://www.base64encode.org/).

  **For Example:**

`%%[
SET @customFont = "AAEAAAAQAQAABAAATFRTSFYQNIsAAAWAAAAA6k9TLzKDu5zQAAABiAAAAGBWRE1YarRyOgAABmwAAAXgY21hcAx2xBwAACE...."
]%%`

- Just below the AMPScript you will then reference your custom font.

  **For example:**

`@font-face {
    font-family: 'YourCustomFontName';
    src: url(data:font/opentype;base64,%%=v(@customFont)=%%);
}`

> **Note**: Font type needs to be set within the font-family if you're
>   Base64Encoding the same font type.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the license on your font to see if you're even allowed to use it in your page.  While I have Base-64 encoded fonts before, it's much easier the license the font and embed the CDN version of it -- like Google Fonts.

Comment: how do i check the licensing details in an OTF file. and how do i know if am allowed to use a specific font on my page?